# Stored Procedure not executing completely inside Azure Function

Tags: python, t-sql, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I want to call stored procedure through an Azure Function (HTTP Trigger).

I was able to execute the stored procedure but it is stopping in the middle of process execution without any error/exception notification.

It actually stops randomly in the middle of the execution because while running a cursor that insert logs in a specific table I get different outputs (sometimes the last log message is: "67. LOG MSG", other time "71. LOG MSG"...)

Note that the exact same procedure with exact same parameters is executing successfully when called inside SSMS.

Any ideas / past experience on a similar issue using Azure Functions & Azure SQL Server (Serverless plan)?

Thanks

I've tried to use a cursor to insert logs in a table to be sure that the issue is not comming from the T-SQL code itself in the Stored Procedure.

The cursor used to try:

```
    DECLARE @i INT = 1;

    WHILE @i <= 100
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @logMsg NVARCHAR(50) = CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '. LOG MSG';        
        EXEC etl.usp_insert_log @logMsg;

        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END
```

I've also tried to catch the error from the Azure function (it uses pyodbc).
The piece of code in the Azure Function that actually execute the Stored procedure:

```
    def execute_non_query(self, query: str, params: list):
        try:
            with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query, params)
                try:
                    self.conn.commit()
                    logging.info("Non-query executed and committed successfully.")
                except pyodbc.Error as e:
                    logging.error(f"Failed to commit changes due to pyodbc.Error: {e}")
                    raise

        except pyodbc.Error as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to execute non-query or commit due to pyodbc.Error: {e}")
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to execute non-query due to general exception: {e}")
            raise
```

Finally,
Absolutely no error is returned and the Execution seems to be completed. (But in fact not)
The time out of the Azure function is configured to 10mins, the time out to the connection string is also high enough. THe execution of the stored procedure should take less than 1 sec.
There are no Lock Timeout, and the only user of this db is this.

Comment: I'd question why you're using a loop in the first place. Can you not achieve what you need to with a set based solution?

Comment: The loop is only used to troubleshoot if the issue is coming from the Stored procedure itself or from the AzureFunction <-> Azure SQL DB.

Initially I was normally processing the stored procedure and adding log the same way, then remarked that it stops randomly at deffirent steps.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your stored procedure put "SET NOCOUNT ON"

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE @i <= 100
BEGIN
    DECLARE @logMsg NVARCHAR(50) = CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '. LOG MSG';        
    EXEC etl.usp_insert_log @logMsg;

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```